# AS3 (animate cc 2018) Why does date keep coming back undefined?

Tags: date, actionscript-3

I'm a beginner, so I'm sensing I'm making a simple mistake but I haven't been able to figure it out or find reference to a similar error on other forums.

My end goal is to create a graphic that changes colour depending on the time of day. Right now my issue is that I can not get a Date object to return anything for the life of me.

This is all I have put in a file called Main.as, that is called in one of the keyframes:

```
        public class Main extends MovieClip {
        var myDate1:Date = new Date();
        trace(myDate1);
        }
```

According to the API, if I don't define a specific date it should just take the current date from my system. But instead of doing the trace I keep getting "error 1120: Access of undefined property myDate1".

Why am I getting this error?

I should note I'm trying to make this for mobile so I've been testing the movie using AIR launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is wrong. You are not supposed to write code directly inside the class body. You need to define methods:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    // Class constructor.
    public function Main()
    {
        super();

        // Output the current date.
        trace(NOW);
    }

    // Static class property that always returns the current date.
    static public function get NOW():Date
    {
        return new Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: A static function isn't necessary to explain this, probably want to just tell him to make a constructor since he's likely very new at this. Upvoting your answer nevertheless.

Comment: @OlinKirkland Well, it works : ) Then a sensible person would google and learn what **static** is. That's my idea of **help**.

Comment: That's fair. Just seemed a little more complicated than it needed to be since all you had to do was add a constructor to his original code.